# Replace value of column A if column B contains string

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
1   Dog Snow    Puppy_1
1   Cat Peanut  Kitten_1
14  Cat Smokey  Cat_9
125 Dog Fido    Dog_9
51  Fish    Jelly   Fish_5
12  Fish    Fishy   Beta_1
```

I want to replace `ColB` with `ColD`'s content if `ColD` contains `Puppy`:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
1   Puppy_1 Snow    Puppy_1
1   Cat Peanut  Kitten_1
14  Cat Smokey  Cat_9
125 Dog Fido    Dog_9
51  Fish    Jelly   Fish_5
12  Fish    Fishy   Beta_1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `grep` to create an index and do the assignment to replace the values of 'ColB' with that of 'ColD'

```
i1 <- grep("Puppy", df1$ColD)
df1$ColB[i1] <- df1$ColD[i1]
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[grepl("Puppy", ColD), ColB := ColD][]
```